# Beautiful Soup Web Scraper on Binance Announcement Page Lags behind by 5 minutes

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, binance

I have built a web scraper using bs4, where the purpose is to get notifications when a new announcement is posted. At the moment I am testing this with the word 'list' instead of all announcement keywords. For some reason when I compare the time it determines a new announcement has been posted versus the actual time it was posted in the website, the time is off by 5 minutes give or take.

[image: This is actual time it was announced]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import time
import sys

x = True
while x == True:
    time.sleep(30)
    # Data for the scraping
    url = "https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement"
    response = get(url)
    html_page = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
    news_list = soup.find_all(class_ = 'css-qinc3w')

    # Create a bag of key words for getting matches
    key_words = ['list', 'token sale', 'open trading', 'opens trading', 'perpetual', 'defi', 'uniswap', 'airdrop', 'adds', 'updates', 'enabled', 'trade', 'support']

    # Empty list
    updated_list = []

    for news in news_list:
        article_text = news.text

        if ("list" in article_text.lower()):
            updated_list.append([article_text])

        if len(updated_list) > 4:
            print(time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) ))
            print(article_text)
            sys.exit()
```

The Response when the length of the list increased by 1 to 5 resulted in printing the following time, and new announcement:
Fri May 28 04:17:39 2021,
Binance Will List Livepeer (LPT)

I am unsure why this is. At first I thought I was being throttled, but looking again at robot.txt, I didn't see any reason why I should be. Moreover I included a sleep time of 30 seconds which should be more than enough to web scrape without any issues. Any help or an alternative solution would be much appreciated.

My question is:

Why is it 5 minutes behind? Why does it not notify me once the website posts it? The program takes 5 minutes longer to recognize there is a new post in comparison to the time it is posted on the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from xrzz import http ## give it try using my simple scratch module
import json

url = "https://www.binance.com/bapi/composite/v1/public/cms/article/list/query?type=1&pageNo=1&pageSize=30"

req = http("GET", url=url, tls=True).body().decode()

key_words = ['list', 'token sale', 'open trading', 'opens trading', 'perpetual', 'defi', 'uniswap', 'airdrop', 'adds', 'updates', 'enabled', 'trade', 'support']

for i in json.loads(req)['data']['catalogs']:
    for o in i['articles']:
        if key_words[0] in o['title']:
            print(o['title'])
```

**Ouput:**

[image: Result]

Comment: I get this result when I run your code: "Notice to API Users on Delisting WAPI Endpoints".

Comment: you specified keyword ("list")  in condition so i used that

Comment: Does anybody know if Binance legally approve web scraping on their news/announcement page?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that the cloudflare server is caching documents
or it was done deliberately by the binance programmers, so that a narrow circle of people could react to the news faster than everyone else.

This is a big problem if you want to get fresh data. If you look at the HTTP headers, you will notice that the `Date:` header is cached by the server, which means that the entire content of the document is cached. I managed to get 2 different `Date:` if I add or remove the gzip header.
`accept-encoding: gzip, deflate`.

I am using the page

```
https://www.binance.com/bapi/composite/v1/public/cms/article/catalog/list/query?catalogId=48&pageNo=1&pageSize=15
```

If you change the `pageSize` parameter, you can get fresh cached responses from the server. But that still doesn't solve the 5 minute delay issue. And I still see the old page.

Your link is :

```
https://www.binance.com/bapi/composite/v1/public/cms/article/list/query?type=1&pageNo=1&pageSize=30 like mine https://www.binance.com/bapi/composite/v1/public/cms/article/catalog/list/query?catalogId=48&pageNo=1&pageSize=15
```

is also cached for 5 seconds. And my guess is that there will be a 5 minute delay as well. I have not found a solution to this problem.

Comment: Isn’t that highly illegal to give access to a select number of people?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer. And I can't prove it. But you can see for yourself if you look at any coin that is added to binance. The situation is as follows:
The binance website publishes news for a narrow circle of people. They are the ones who see the news first. If you look at the price chart of this coin, you can see that they start trading in large volumes in the first minutes after the news is published. Where does the value come from if, in fact, the news has not yet been published on the binance website? Who are all these people who buy and sell? The question is, of course, a rhetorical one :)

Comment: PS: Didn't you manage to force the server to give fresh data? Not cached.

Comment: Nope still have the same issue where it’s 5 minute behind

Comment: @MattHodson No nothing was found to solve this problem